# Iterate through each "match" (Ruby regex)

Tags: ruby, regex

Okay, I can find a Regex match in a string, and do some captures.
Now, what if my string has many matches? Let's say my code finds out the number inside parenthesis in a string. The code will find the number in a string like

> (5)

But what if the string is

> (5) (6) (7)

I need a way to iterate through these three elements. I've seen tutorials, but they seem to only talk about one-time matches...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use the `String#scan` method. See documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan).

Answer (score 9):

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) can be used to find all matches of a given regex:

```
"(5) (6) (7)".scan(/\(\d+\)/) { |match| puts "Found: #{match}" }
# Prints:
Found: (5)
Found: (6)
Found: (7)
```

You can use positive look behind (`?<=`) and look ahead (`?=`) to exclude the parenthesis from your results:

```
"(5) (6) (7)".scan(/(?<=[(])\d+(?=\))/) { |match| puts "Found: #{match}" }
# Prints:
Found: 5
Found: 6
Found: 7
```

If you don't pass a block to `scan`, it returns an array with all matches:

```
"(5) (6) (7)".scan(/(?<=[(])\d+(?=\))/)
=> ["5", "6", "7"]
```